# importing react-leaflet in react with webpack returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-leaflet

I am trying to simply import react-leaflet without rendering any maps in my project but it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

I know for sure it's from the import statement. It even points to it in the error on line 2. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Map } from 'react-leaflet'

export default class MyMap extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div><h1>E</h1></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code works fine without the import statement. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the react-leaflet website (https://react-leaflet.js.org/) it looks like the Map component is a named export. When importing named exports you need to wrap the component you're importing with curly braces:

```
import { Map } from 'react-leaflet';
```

Some information on named and default exports [here](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/a-not-so-in-depth-explanation-of-es6-modules-import-and-export-13a80300f2f0)

I haven't used react-leaflet myself but looking over their website it seems they have some good examples to help get you started. [It may be worth taking a look if you're new to it.](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/examples.html)

Comment: My apologies. I had already tried that this paste was from when I tried doing the opposite. Edited it.